# ADF Lift and Shift SSIS using Vnet

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-server

We are trying to Lift and shift Existing SSIS Packages to Azure using ADF Azure SSIS Integration Runtime using VNet Configuration.

We were successfully created the VNET in Azure and we are able to connect using that.

Problem is when we execute the Package using ADF we are getting the below error:

```
Package:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: \"Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server\"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: \"Login timeout expired\".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: \"Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server\"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: \"A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.\".An OLE DB record is available.  Source: \"Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server\"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: \"SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. \".
6/23/2021 12:29:29 PM +00:00 : Data Flow Task:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager \"xxxxx\\SQLExpress.SampleDB.sa\" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
6/23/2021 12:29:29 PM +00:00 : Data Flow Task:Error: OLE DB Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C."
```

Update with error image:
[image: Link for the Error image]

Updated with Conn_Config:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    -<DTSConfiguration>


    -<DTSConfigurationHeading>

    <DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedDate="6/24/2021 3:45:49 PM" GeneratedFromPackageID="{5104305D-A0CE-4C60-B044-1DB05C92AB7C}" GeneratedFromPackageName="Package1" GeneratedBy="xxxxSYS\xxxxxxxxxx"/>

    </DTSConfigurationHeading>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Boolean" Path="\Package.Connections[Src_Server\SQL2017.Test.sa].Properties[ConnectByProxy]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>-1</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="String" Path="\Package.Connections[Src_Server\SQL2017.Test.sa].Properties[ConnectionString]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=Src_Server\SQL2017;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Test;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Auto Translate=False;</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Int32" Path="\Package.Connections[Src_Server\SQL2017.Test.sa].Properties[ConnectRetryCount]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>1</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Int32" Path="\Package.Connections[Src_Server\SQL2017.Test.sa].Properties[ConnectRetryInterval]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>5</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Boolean" Path="\Package.Connections[Src_Server\SQL2017.Test.sa].Properties[ConnectUsingManagedIdentity]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>0</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="String" Path="\Package.Connections[Src_Server\SQL2017.Test.sa].Properties[Description]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue/>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="String" Path="\Package.Connections[Src_Server\SQL2017.Test.sa].Properties[InitialCatalog]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>Test</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="String" Path="\Package.Connections[Src_Server\SQL2017.Test.sa].Properties[Name]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>Src_Server\SQL2017.Test.sa</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Int32" Path="\Package.Connections[Src_Server\SQL2017.Test.sa].Properties[ProtectionLevel]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>1</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Boolean" Path="\Package.Connections[Src_Server\SQL2017.Test.sa].Properties[RetainSameConnection]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>0</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Int32" Path="\Package.Connections[Src_Server\SQL2017.Test.sa].Properties[Scope]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>0</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Boolean" Path="\Package.Connections[dest_server.database.windows.net.dest_DB.xxxx].Properties[ConnectByProxy]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>-1</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="String" Path="\Package.Connections[dest_server.database.windows.net.dest_DB.xxxx].Properties[ConnectionString]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=dest_server.database.windows.net;User ID=xxxx;Initial Catalog=dest_DB;Provider=MSOLEDBSQL.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Int32" Path="\Package.Connections[dest_server.database.windows.net.dest_DB.xxxx].Properties[ConnectRetryCount]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>1</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Int32" Path="\Package.Connections[dest_server.database.windows.net.dest_DB.xxxx].Properties[ConnectRetryInterval]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>5</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Boolean" Path="\Package.Connections[dest_server.database.windows.net.dest_DB.xxxx].Properties[ConnectUsingManagedIdentity]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>0</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="String" Path="\Package.Connections[dest_server.database.windows.net.dest_DB.xxxx].Properties[Description]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue/>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="String" Path="\Package.Connections[dest_server.database.windows.net.dest_DB.xxxx].Properties[InitialCatalog]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>dest_DB</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="String" Path="\Package.Connections[dest_server.database.windows.net.dest_DB.xxxx].Properties[Name]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>dest_server.database.windows.net.dest_DB.xxxx</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Int32" Path="\Package.Connections[dest_server.database.windows.net.dest_DB.xxxx].Properties[ProtectionLevel]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>1</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Boolean" Path="\Package.Connections[dest_server.database.windows.net.dest_DB.xxxx].Properties[RetainSameConnection]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>0</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>


    -<Configuration ValueType="Int32" Path="\Package.Connections[dest_server.database.windows.net.dest_DB.xxxx].Properties[Scope]" ConfiguredType="Property">

    <ConfiguredValue>0</ConfiguredValue>

    </Configuration>

    </DTSConfiguration>
```

Comment: As per the Error message we could see the error occurs when the remote access is not enabled or the connection string specifies a provider that is not supported. Could you please help me with your config file connection code?

Comment: Thanks @IpsitaDash-MT for your reply. I have updated my question with the config details you asked. Kindly look in to it.

Comment: Could you please try to use SQLOLEDB.1 rather than SQLNCLI.1 in the line no.7. Here is the same scenario:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fab0e3bf-4adf-4f17-b9f6-7b7f9db6523c/communication-link-failure-when-connecting-to-remote-database?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Hi @IpsitaDash-MT, there isno luck on that chg... pls chk the error image attached with the question for the error description.

Comment: As per the error in the image we could see BLOBNOT EXIST, it could be because of 2 reasons:

The reference that the user has been holding to the actual resource doesn’t really exist.
The firewall that might block outgoing requests to Azure Blob Storage, could be checked running the same query using a different network.

Comment: @Sree - please edit your question to contain properly formatted text when including things like code or errors, and avoid images of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important. I attempted to format the rest of your output (though you included error text containing lots of escaped-character content).